# Is my code actually written in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently working on a SQL project. My professor wants the code to be written in T-SQL, and I just learned it today. I bought a course on Udemy called T-SQL introduction, but the code looks very similar to how I have been coding before. I have checked on Google, and it looks no where near what my code looks like. Can someone check out my code for me to see if it looks to be in T-SQL before I submit it?

```
CREATE TABLE Vet
(
    [VET_NUM] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Vet_VetNum PRIMARY KEY,
    [LAST_NAME] CHAR(20),
    [FIRST_NAME] CHAR(20),
    [STREET] CHAR(30),
    [CITY] CHAR(20),
    [STATE] CHAR(20),
    [POSTAL_CODE] CHAR(20),
    [SALARY] DECIMAL(8,2),
    [DEGREE] CHAR(20),
    [POSITION] CHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Owner
(
    [OWNER_NUM] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Owner_OwnerNum PRIMARY KEY,
    [OWNER_NAME] CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [STREET] CHAR(30),
    [CITY] CHAR(20),
    [STATE] CHAR(20),
    [POSTAL_CODE] CHAR(20)

);

CREATE TABLE Pet
(
    [PET_NUM] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Pet_PetNum PRIMARY KEY,
    [PET_NAME] CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    [STREET] CHAR(30),
    [CITY] CHAR(15),
    [STATE] CHAR(2),
    [POSTAL_CODE] CHAR(5),
    [BREED] CHAR(20),
    [OWNER_NUM] INT CONSTRAINT Fk_Pet_OwnerNum FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Owner(OWNER_NUM),-- Added Foreign key reference 

)

CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
    [APPOINTMENT_NUM] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Appointment_AppointmentNum PRIMARY KEY,
    [APPOINTMENT_DATE] DATE,
    [VET_NUM] INT  CONSTRAINT Fk_Appointment_VetNum FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES VET(VET_NUM),-- Added Foreign key reference  );
    [PET_NUM] INT  CONSTRAINT Fk_Appointment_PetNum FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pet(PET_NUM)-- Added Foreign key reference  );
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT vet ON
INSERT INTO vet ([vet_num],[last_name],[first_name],[street],[city],[state], [postal_code], [salary],[degree],[position]) 
VALUES (1, 'Skechley', 'Cristine', '24340 7th   Plaza', 'Pittsburgh', 'PA', '15274', 88053.30, 'Masters', 'Vet'), 
       (2, 'Fishpoole', 'Sig', '06784 Anthes Point', 'Philadelphia', 'PA', '19184', 45525.56, 'Associates', 'Receptionist'), 
       (3, 'Stother', 'Rycca', '04304 Superior Hill', 'Allentown', 'PA', '18105', 90553.37, 'Masters', 'Vet'), 
       (4, 'Scandrite', 'Kerrill', '30320 Express Crossing', 'Harrisburg', 'PA', '17126', 102553.59, 'Doctorates', 'Vet'), 
       (5, 'Glassman', 'Rhett', '33418 Tomscot Trail', 'Mc Keesport', 'PA', '15134', 56052.24, 'Bachelor', 'Management'), 
       (6, 'Gioan', 'Rab', '1 Pennsylvania Street', 'Hatfield', 'PA', '19440', 35880.76, 'Student', 'Janitor'), 
       (7, 'Patel', 'Dhruv', '24411 Jean Drive', 'Hatfield', 'PA', '19440', 42790.88, 'Student', 'Receptionist'), 
       (8, 'Smith', 'Giana', '24 Malple Street', 'Lansdale', 'PA', '19446', 35880.22, 'Student', 'Janitor'), 
       (9, 'Lopez', 'Briana', 'Orvilla', 'Allentown', 'PA', '18105', 74880.47, 'Masters', 'Vet'), 
       (10, 'Sam', 'Hector', 'Orvilla', 'Allentown', 'PA', '18105', 74880.47, 'Masters', 'Vet'); 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT vet OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT owner ON
INSERT INTO owner ([owner_num],[owner_name],[street],[city],[state],[postal_code]) 
VALUES (11, 'Sammantha Rodgers','96372 Dexter Terrace','Erie', 'PA','16510'), 
       (12,'Jenkins Tim','486 Marcy Avenue','Philadelphia','PA','19184'), 
       (13,'Smith Bobby','03781 Meadow Ridge','Erie','PA','16510'), 
       (14,'Parker Aaron','80 Marcy Place','Harrisburg','PA','17126'), 
       (15,'Gil Malcomn','239 Tony Point','Harrisburg','PA','17110'), 
       (16,'Ramsey Torrey','0778 Columbus Park','Philadelphia','PA','19178'), 
       (17,'Novak Cole','63519 Warbler Way','Pittsburgh','PA','15261'), 
       (18,'Cunningham Dylan','0728 Esch Terrace','Pittsburgh ','PA','15274'), 
       (19,'Barclay Liam','36 John Wall Parkway','Pittsburgh ','PA','15210'), 
       (20,'Perez Joeseph','Hatfield Village','Hatfield','PA','19440');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT owner OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT appointment ON
INSERT INTO appointment ([APPOINTMENT_NUM],[appointment_date],[VET_NUM],[PET_NUM]) 
VALUES (21,'12/11/2017',1,25), 
       (30,'12/12/2017',2,26), 
       (23,'12/12/2017',1,27), 
       (29,'12/13/2017',4,23), 
       (25,'12/14/2017',5,22); 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT appointment OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Pet ON
INSERT INTO Pet ([PET_NUM], [PET_NAME], [STREET], [CITY], [STATE],[POSTAL_CODE], [BREED], [OWNER_NUM]) 
VALUES (21,'Jimmy','96372 Dexter Terrace','Erie', 'PA','16510','Affenpinscher',11), 
       (22,'Lily','486 Marcy Avenue','Philadelphia','PA','19184','American Bulldog',12), 
       (23,'Sally','03781 Meadow Ridge','Erie','PA','16510','American Eskimo Dog',13), 
       (24,'Joey','80 Marcy Place','Harrisburg','PA','17126','Barbet',14), 
       (25,'Rocky','239 Tony Point','Harrisburg','PA','17110','Papillon',15), 
       (26,'Sam','0778 Columbus Park','Philadelphia','PA','19178','McNab',16), 
       (27,'Chloe','63519 Warbler Way','Pittsburgh','PA','15261','Mountain Cur',17), 
       (28,'Mike','0728 Esch Terrace','Pittsburgh ','PA','15274','Pug',18), 
       (29,'Bruno','36 John Wall Parkway','Pittsburgh ','PA','15210','Pomeranian',19), 
       (30,'Daisy','Hatfield Village','Hatfield','PA','19440','Rat Terrier',20),
       (31,'Tim','Hatfield Village','Hatfield','PA','19440','German Shepherd',20);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Pet OFF

DELETE 
FROM Appointment
Where [APPOINTMENT_DATE] = '12/12/2017';

UPDATE Owner
SET [OWNER_NAME] = 'Jennifer Rodgers'
WHERE [OWNER_NAME] = 'Sammantha Rodgers'
```

Comment: The delete and update code looks very similar to what I have been coding before

Comment: Transact SQL is commonly known as t-sql which is just the MS dialect of ANSI SQL. As such...yes this is t-sql.

Comment: I see a stray comma in the Pet table!

Comment: Those square brackets are unnecessary anyway.

Comment: If you can run in in SSMS without error, you are good.

Comment: The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) for the `tsql` tag provides a helpful summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very few syntax "clues" in your code to distinguish your script from "generic" SQL. e.g.

```
[VET_NUM] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

The use of `[]` for names is unique to T-SQL and the terminology `IDENTITY(1,1)` isn't used by other dbms vendors either.

+edit:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT  tablename ON/OFF
```

Is also [T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/sql/t-sql/language-reference)

Comment: The absence of `;` is also special to T-SQL (or at least the Microsoft Tools)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah! Yes, good pick-up. One gets so used to these things. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original question: It's t-sql and it actually runs. (works on my machine).
But if I were you, I'd just update some parts of it to match more or less accepted conventions. 
E.g.

- Skip caps lock and underscores on column names, use CamelCase
  instead.
- Instead of _NUM in keys use ID.
- "Owner" is a reserved word    in    SQL, not necessarily, buy you
  might want to change it.
- Instead of char(XX) data type use varchar(XX). In named places where
  length varies char(XX) is almost never a good idea. And I had a
  couple of MVPs claiming that char is actually never a good
  idea.
- You don't really need square brackets, it's usually used to bypass
  reserved       words (anything that SSMS highlights as blue)

All those are debatable, and for a person who learned it only a day ago, I think it's good.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure with the tips you gave, it will help my grade tremendously!